# Ruby method not being seen

Tags: ruby, module

I have a method `known_args` being called from the main class of my script, it is included in the module, `Validations`, but for some reason I'm getting:

```
undefined method `known_args' for PasswordGenerator:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Strange thing is, even when I place it back in the main class, I get the same error.

password_generator.rb

```
require 'securerandom'
require_relative 'validations'

class PasswordGenerator

    include Validations

    class Array
    # If +number+ is greater than the size of the array, the method
    # will simply return the array itself sorted randomly
      def randomly_pick(number)
            sort_by{ rand }.slice(0...number)
        end
    end

    def password_generator length, charsets
        #Set allowed characters
        valid_characters = charsets
        #Intitialise empty string
        password = ""
        length.times do
            #we cannot do "randomly_pick(length)" because we want repeating characters 
            password << valid_characters.randomly_pick(1).first
        end
        #Return password
        password
    end

    def username_generator
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(calc_usename_length)
    end

    def calc_usename_length
        length = (12..32).to_a
        length.sample
    end
    ############### Input, checks and validations
    def charsets
        special_chars = [ '@', '£', "#", "%", "?", "€", "-", "+", "=", "*", "_", "~", "^", "|", ".", "[","]", "{", "}" ]
        other = ('0'..'9').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a
        combined = use_special? ? insert_special(special_chars, other) : no_special(other)
        combined
    end

    def use_special?
        return true if @use_special_argument == 's' || @use_special_argument == 'S'
        return false if @use_special_argument == 'b' || @use_special_argument == 'B'
    end

    def insert_special(special_chars, other)
        other + special_chars
    end

    def no_special(other)
        other
    end

    def argument_check length
        is_integer(length) && check_length(length) ? pass(length) : fail
    end

    def pass length
        password_generator(length, charsets) 
    end

    length = ARGV[0].to_i
    @use_special_argument = ARGV[1]

    unless known_args.include? @use_special_argument
        puts
        puts "Specify whether or not to use special characters."
        puts "Use special characters: 's' || 'S'"
        puts "No special characters: 'b' || 'B'"
        puts
        puts "Unknown argument: '#{@use_special_argument}'. Aborting"
        exit_script
    end

    puts
    puts "Username: " + username_generator
    puts "Password: " + argument_check(length)
    puts
    puts "Complete. Exiting"
    exit_script

end


validations.rb

    module Validations

    def is_integer length
        length.is_a? Integer
    end

    def check_length length
        length > 0
    end

    def fail
        'Argument must be integer and greater than 0. Recommend max length available by application. 64 if unknown'
    end

    def known_args
        known_args_array = ['s', 'S', 'b', 'B' ]
        known_args_array
    end

    def exit_script
        Kernel.exit(false)
    end

end
```

Comment: `sort_by { rand }` is not doing what you expect. It is likely to produce an invalid ordering (e.g., `a > b > c > a`), with unpredictable results.

Comment: Ok, what would you suggest as a solution?

Comment: `class Array; def randomly_pick(number); shuffle[0, number]; end; end; a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; a.randomly_pick(3) #=> [6, 1, 4]; a.randomly_pick(999) #=> [4, 3, 6, 1, 5, 2]`.

Comment: The above is for sampling wihout replacement. For sampling with replacement: `def randomly_pick(number); [size, number].min.times.map { self[rand(self.size)] }; end; [1,2,3].randomly_pick(2)
#=> [3, 3]; [1,2,3].randomly_pick(999) #=> [2, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `sort_by { rand }` should be fine. [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) is documented to be a Schwartzian Transform so the sort keys are only computed once. I'd still use `shuffle` though.

Comment: @muistooshort You mean call `shuffle` of the character array?

Comment: Yeah, instead of calling `sort_by { rand }`, call `shuffle` instead.

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks μ. Yes, of course. Sorry for the time-waster, Richard.

Comment: @muistooshort No problem at all, just had to check, so I have this now, `sort_by{ shuffle }.slice(0...number)`. Why is `shuffle` better than `rand`?

Comment: Richard, it's just a question of whether you want to sample with (`rand`) or without (`shuffle`) replacement.

Comment: @muistooshort Ok mo worries. Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't you just want to `shuffle` (and `slice`), rather than `sort_by{ shuffle }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at the error message:

```
undefined method `known_args' for PasswordGenerator:Class (NoMethodError)
```

That message is saying that Ruby can't find a `known_args` method in `PasswordGenerator`, not in an instance of `PasswordGenerator`.

Saying `include Validations` adds `known_args` from `Validations` as an instance method but you're trying to call it as a class method.

You can either set up a `Validations.included` method to add `known_args` the includer when `include Validations` happens or, better IMO, move all your code into an instance method:

```
class PasswordGenerator
  #...

  def perform
    length = ARGV[0].to_i
    @use_special_argument = ARGV[1]

    unless known_args.include? @use_special_argument
        puts
        puts "Specify whether or not to use special characters."
        puts "Use special characters: 's' || 'S'"
        puts "No special characters: 'b' || 'B'"
        puts
        puts "Unknown argument: '#{@use_special_argument}'. Aborting"
        exit_script
    end

    puts
    puts "Username: " + username_generator
    puts "Password: " + argument_check(length)
    puts
    puts "Complete. Exiting"
    exit_script
  end
end
```

and then say:

```
PasswordGenerator.new.perform
```

to crank things up.

Comment: That's much better. Thanks.
I Had to move the reopened Array class outside of the PasswordGenerator as it was showing, `undefined method randomly_pick' for #<Array:0x007feeb1815a18` class though, any idea why this was?

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. You were working with `PasswordGenerator::Array` rather than `::Array`.